# Serialized form returning undefined with multiple buttons

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, forms, button

I am currently trying to pass a form to ajax, utilizing two different buttons.  Currently, I only have one button active, but I have found my form is undefined - so ajax does not get the form.  I believe my issue must lie in how I am calling the button events (perhaps the form is not submitting?), but do not know how to properly call the buttons.

PHP(HTML)

```
echo "<br /><br /><br /><h1>Withdraw Credit</h1>
        <body>
            <div class=\"formcontainer\">
            <form id=\"requestcreditform\">
              <div class=\"container\">
                <label for=\"credit_requested\"><strong>Credit Requested</strong></label>
                <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"userid\" id=\"userid\" value=".$activeuser[0]->id.">
                <input type=\"number\" name=\"creditreq\" placeholder=\"".$remaining_credit."\" id=\"creditreq\" required>
                <br /><p>This change will be reflected upon submission and your credit processed shortly afterwards.  All loans begin with a 20% interest rate, which compounds annually.  Please verify the requested credit is correct prior to hitting the \"Request via Check\" button.  Checks will be addressed to the client and shipped to the attorney's practice.  Thank you.
                </p>
              </div>
                <button id=\"request_check_button\" type=\"submit\"><strong>Request via Check (Standard Shipping)</strong></button>
                
                <button id=\"request_expedited_check_button\" type=\"submit\"><strong>Request via Check (Expedited Shipping + $15)</strong></button>
           </form>
            </div>
          </body>
          <br /><br /><br />
        </html>";
```

JQuery

```
(function($){
  $('#request_check_button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var endpoint = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>';
            
    var form = $('#requestcreditform').serialize();        
            
    var formdata = new FormData;
    
    formdata.append('action', 'ordercheck');
    formdata.append('ordercheck', form);
    
    $.ajax(endpoint, {
      type: 'POST',
      data: formdata,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      
      success:function(res) {
        alert(res.data);
        location.reload();
      },
      error: function(err) {
      }
    })
  })
})(jQuery)
```

I've also tried looking for the individual IDs of the html elements, but that actually broke my ajax functionality - moving me further from finding my solution.  The ajax seems to be correct - and the problem is on my undefined form data.

Edit:  In the end, I gave up trying to submit my form with multiple buttons and reverted to a single button design, substituting my multiple options with checkboxes.

Comment: Can you provide the *rendered* HTML (as seen in browser view-source or browser inspect-element)?  See [mcve]

Comment: Assuming your HTML is correct and `$('#requestcreditform').serialize()` provides valid data, then check the network tab when you POST to ensure the data is being passed.  If it is, then your issue is server-side in how you receive the `ordercheck` data.

Comment: To get the event for both buttons, use: `$('#request_check_button,#request_expedited_check_button')` but then you'll need to check which button was clicked:  `this.id==`